# Project Euler #23 in Java

Tags: java

I've spent quite a while working on Problem #23 on Project Euler.

The answer the program below gives me is **4190428**, and I can't figure out why.

I think it's probably a one or two character mistake somewhere.

```
public long problem23() {

    ArrayList<Integer> abundantNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int limit = 28123;
    for(int i = 2; i < limit; i++) {
        if(isAbundantNum(i)) {
            abundantNumbers.add(i);
        }
    }

    boolean [] abundantSum = new boolean [limit+1];
    for(int a = 0; a < abundantNumbers.size(); a++) {
        for(int b = 1; b < abundantNumbers.size(); b++) {
            int temp = abundantNumbers.get(a) + abundantNumbers.get(b); 
            if(temp <= limit) {
                abundantSum[temp] = true;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    long sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
        if(!abundantSum[i]) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

public boolean isAbundantNum(int n) {
    int factorSum = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        if(n%i == 0) {
            factorSum += i; factorSum += n/i; 
        }
    }
    if(factorSum > n) {
        System.out.println(n);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Edit: Added `isAbundantNum(int n)` method.

Comment: where is your `isAbundantNum` function

Comment: I added it above, sorry about that.

Comment: My head just exploded. It's a miracle I could type this comment.

Comment: Is my code too hard to follow...?

Comment: No! It's the question you're trying to answer! Struggling to regain consciousness...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 bugs...

```
for(int b = 1; b < abundantNumbers.size(); b++) {
```

'b' should start at zero not 1

```
for(int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
    if(n%i == 0) {
        factorSum += i; factorSum += n/i; 
    }
}
```

Factoring like that gives you duplicates (like 2*2 = 4, you're getting both 2s).

Try something like:

```
    for(int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if(n%i == 0) {
            factorSum += i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Both bugs threw off my answer.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another implementation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class P23 {

    final static int MIN = 12;
    final static int MAX = 28123;
    static boolean numbers[] = new boolean[MAX+1];
    static List<Integer> abundantNumbers = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        generateAbundants(MIN, MAX);
        int size = abundantNumbers.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < size; j++) {
                int current = abundantNumbers.get(i) + abundantNumbers.get(j);
                if (current <= MAX) {
                    numbers[current] = true;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= MAX ; i++ ) {
            if ( numbers[i] == false ) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    private static int sumOfProperDivisors(int x) {
        int sum = 1;
        int squareRoot = (int) Math.sqrt(x);
        for (int i = 2; i <= squareRoot; i++) {
            if (x % i == 0) {
                sum += i;
                sum += x / i;
            }
        }
        // if x is a perfect square, it's square root was added twice
        if (squareRoot * squareRoot == x) {
            sum -= squareRoot;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private static boolean isAbundant(int x) {
        if (x < sumOfProperDivisors(x)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static void generateAbundants(int min, int max) {
        for (int i = min; i < max; i++) {
            if (isAbundant(i)) {
                abundantNumbers.add(i);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Time: 455 ms**

**Explanation:**

- The default value for `j` is `i`. You can take `j = 0` ( as Ted Bigham said -> `b` in that case ), because it will work, but it will take into consideration every number twice ( 12+20 = 20+12 ). It's more efficient to start from `i`. Why isn't it good to start from `1`? Because you can loose solutions: in my example 24 = 12 + 12.
- Regarding the `for` loop containing the divisors part, you can use the approach containing `sqrt` because it's more efficient ( O(sqrt(n)) instead of O(n) ), but you have to adjust it. In my example you can see that I have `<= squareRoot` because if I don't use `=`, it will skip some values ( E.g.: 6 is divisor for 36, but you don't include it in your solution ). Because I counted `6` twice, I remove one of those roots. Of course that Ted's method is good, but sometimes it's better to have an improved performance, even if the simplicity is affected.